# which auto-complete mode to use for writing English in Emacs

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

What's the best Emacs auto-complete mode to use for writing prose in English? My main requirement would be to automatically complete its best guess as to the MOST LIKELY match with a single keystroke, rather than forcing me to navigate and choose which completion to fill in.

So that for instance if I typed in DISADV and hit ESCAPE, it would automatically complete it to DISADVANTAGE since that's the most likely completion.

It would be even better if it could automatically complete it just from hitting SPACE, if and when there's only one possible completion.

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried M-/ (dabbrev-expand)? It guesses and fills in something automatically, and if you don't like it you can use M-/ again to try something different. http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryCompletion has lots of different packages that might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You can try hippie-expand, which will complete from all your open buffers, picking up words that you use more often.